# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.sun.jna.Library com.sun.jna.Native.load(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried to get an image to text using doOCR, but it results with an error as shown below. Even I tried adding new jna libraries even though it resulted with same error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.sun.jna.Library com.sun.jna.Native.load(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)'
> at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:83)
> at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.(TessAPI.java:42)
> at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:442)
> at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:238)
> at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:210)
> at imgcaptcha.image.main(image.java:50)

**CODE:**

```
try
        
        {
        
            //driver.manage().window().maximize();
            
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            driver.get("https://www.marketinginternetdirectory.com/submit.php");
            
            WebElement Image=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/img"));
            
            File src =Image.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            
            String path="D:\\Automation projects\\imgcaptcha\\captchaimg\\captcha.png";
            
            FileHandler.copy(src, new File(path));
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            
            ITesseract image1 = new Tesseract(); 
            
            String str = image1.doOCR(new File(path));
            
            System.out.println("OCR Done");
            
            System.out.println(str);
        
        }
    
        catch(Exception e)
        
        {

            System.out.println("exception caught: " +e.getMessage());
        
        }
}
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
   <dependencies>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.0</version>
</dependency>
     
     </dependencies>
```

Please give me a solution to fix this part.

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You error suggests that the problem is in `LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance()` method. Once check that you've updated the JNA libraries to version 5.13.0, as specified in your dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I have added latest version of JNA Libraries, even though it results with that error. I have listed my dependencies above.